# Python - multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError while downloading images

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I have been trying to download images from Flickr. I first scrape all the URL's from Flickr and then I feed the URL list to a function that downloads the images in those URL's for me.

```
def download_link(directory,url):
    flName = str(directory + str(os.path.basename(url)))
    urlretrieve(url, flName)

download = partial(download_link, download_dir)
with Pool(10) as p:
    p.map(download, urlList)
```

The issue I see is that, the script does not fail every time. I have particularly noticed, that when I rerun the script too often it fails too often. And it downloads a handful of URL's before it fails. And I do not particularly suspect that there is just some bad URL in the list that is causing this failure. **Is there is a reason for this?** 
Here is the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocialMediaImageExtracts.py", line 62, in <module>
    __main__(sys.argv)
  File "SocialMediaImageExtracts.py", line 59, in __main__
    p.map(download, urlList)
  File "/Users/sreejithmenon/anaconda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Users/sreejithmenon/anaconda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x1037de0f0>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Edit: I am sure that there is no bad URL since, it just ran for all URLs in that set for one time and now it failed again*